# Unpaid deduction in odoo v8 not appear in the payslip

Tags: odoo

i create different rule for salary with the following sequence but the unpaid not appear when i create the payslip, also the absent which for employee who late didn't work well

```
house allowance 101
transport allowance 100
absent 78
unpaid 77
retire 76
basic 32
net 200
```

thank you

Comment: That's too bad? Did you have a question?

Comment: Yes can you tell me what's the problem so I can solve it to work fine